# PHP Remove text before and after element

Tags: php, dom

I have some database rows with a lot of text but I only want to select a specific text.

Example:

```
<strong>Lorem</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
</ul>

<strong>Ipsum</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>

<strong>Third</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Some words</li>
    <li>More words</li>
</ul>
```

I only want to select the Ipsum part with the ul element and ignore the rest. I was trying to work with `DOMXPath->evaluate('//text()[contains()]')` but this only shows the Ipsum text and not the elements.

EDIT:
The exact output I want is:

```
<strong>Ipsum</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```

The code I tried (I have tried more but this is the last result):

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($text);

$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$result = $x->evaluate("//text()[contains(., 'Ipsum')]");

$result->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

This shows only the Ipsum text and not the list elements.

Comment: Can you edit your question, adding the exact output you're after?

Comment: And the code you say you used that filed

Comment: What is this "Ipsum part"? Is it always a strong with the exact word "Ipsum" in, or is it always the second of three string tags?

Comment: So would it be correct to re-phrase this as you’re looking for all `strong` elements that do _not_ have exactly `Ipsum` as their text content, and you then want to remove those and their following element sibling (the UL) …?

Comment: I have updated the post. 
andres : It is always the exact word "Ipsum", it can be in a different order.
CBroe : I am looking for all strong elements "Ipsum" and their list

Comment: Is regex possible/ok to use? https://regex101.com/r/s0n0Em/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your trying to get 2 nodes, the way I've done it is to use 2 XPath expressions...

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($text);

$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$result = $x->evaluate("//strong[contains(., 'Ipsum')]");
$result1 = $x->evaluate("//strong[contains(., 'Ipsum')]/following-sibling::ul");

echo $d->saveHTML($result->item(0)).PHP_EOL;
echo $d->saveHTML($result1->item(0)).PHP_EOL;
```

Which outputs.

```
<strong>Ipsum</strong>
<ul>
<li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match.
It's not an ideal tool for HTML and XML but it can work with strict enough patterns.

This pattern captures strong tag with Ipsum and down to next strong tag or end of string.

```
$re = '/(<strong>Ipsum<\/strong>.*?)(<strong>|\z)/s';
$str =  '<strong>Lorem</strong>
<ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Ipsum</li>
</ul>

<strong>Ipsum</strong>
<ul>
<li>Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
</ul>

<strong>Third</strong>
<ul>
<li>Some words</li>
<li>More words</li>
</ul>';

preg_match($re, $str, $match);

var_dump($matches);
```

https://regex101.com/r/s0n0Em/2